# A way to group config files in a .config directory

Tags: javascript, scaffolding

My javascript projects' root is becoming cluttered with configuration files. I am aware that CI systems and IDEs expect that, by convention, those files would reside in the root. Yet I wanted to ask whether there is a way, perhaps for some of those files, to relocate them to a /.config path?

[image: structure]

Comment: You can put the documentation markdown and the webpack config in sub-directories, but I don't think it's possible with the dot files (.eslint, .babelrc, etc.)